# What do the new tidy eval braces {{ }} do? Passing arguments across functions and using as_label

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyeval

While looking to fix an issue with passing arguments from a `dplyr`-based function to a `ggplot` function recently, I was surprised to discover that there was a brand-new [programming with `dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette and a corresponding version for [`ggplot2` in packages](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html). I was hoping to kill two birds with one stone: learning the new tidyeval incantations and getting rid of my problem.

I wanted a function to do custom plotting, which may occasionally be called by another function that does some pre-processing of the data supplied; but it was failing as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

my_plot <- function(df, x_var, colour_var = "cyl") {
  
  char_col <- df %>%
    pull(colour_var) %>%
    is.character()
  
  if(!char_col ) cat(colour_var, "is not character.")
  
  
  ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = !! ensym(x_var), y = hp, colour = !!ensym(colour_var))) +
    labs(title = paste("Passed in x variable:", x_var))
  
}

process_n_plot <- function(x_var, val, colour_var) {

  
  cat("You are filtering variable", x_var, "\n")
  
  mtcars %>% 
    filter(!!ensym(x_var)  > val) %>% 
    my_plot(x_var = x_var, colour_var = colour_var)
  
  
}

process_n_plot("disp", 200, "cyl")
#> You are filtering variable "disp" 
#> cyl is not character.
```

[image]

```r
my_plot(mtcars, "disp", "cyl")
#> cyl is not character.
```

[image]

I realise I could have just used `aes_string`... But I was actually operating in `ggraph` and forgot 'cause I'd never used `aes_string` there. Also, having strings as arguments was me assuming it would the most straightforward way, but still preferred to call the functions with unquoted variable names.

So, things worked when calling `my_plot` directly; and almost worked when called "indirectly". The vignettes didn't quite cover these use cases, so I had to test.

However, replacing `!!ensym(x_var)` with `{{x_var}}` above does not work; neither does the naïve approach below with bare variable names. `{{}}` as per the vignettes seems to combine the steps of `enquo(s)` and `!!(!)` but that poses a problem when trying to use something like `as_label`/`as_string`, which want you to `enquo` but not `!!`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

my_plot <- function(df, x_var, colour_var = "cyl") {
  
  discrete_col <- df %>%
    pull(colour_var) %>%
    is.character()
  
  if(!discrete_col) cat(colour_var, "is not character.")
  
  
  ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = {{ x_var }}, y = hp, colour = {{ colour_var }})) +
    labs(title = paste("Passed in x variable:", as_label({{ x_var }})))
  
}

process_n_plot <- function(x_var, val, colour_var) {

  
  cat("You are filtering variable", as_label( {{ x_var }} ), "\n")
  
  mtcars %>% 
    filter({{ x_var }}  > val) %>% 
    my_plot(x_var = x_var, colour_var = colour_var)
  
  
}

process_n_plot(disp, 200, cyl)
#> Error in is_quosure(quo): object 'disp' not found

my_plot(mtcars, disp, cyl)
#> Error: object 'cyl' not found
```

Note that removing the `labs` does make `my_plot` work fine, as expected from the vignette.

Comment: i don't use them, but this should be the man page `?rlang:::\`{{\``

Comment: yes, I forgot to list that.. Unfortunately, the information in there is a big hard to parse (forgive the pun)... I guess the vignette is intended for the simplest of use cases; for anything else you should try to understand the whole set of tools, which I was clearly struggling with!

Answer (score 3):

While waiting for the real experts to explain some of the gory details, a solution is as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

my_plot <- function(df, x_var, colour_var = cyl) {
  
  char_col <- df %>%
    pull({{colour_var}}) %>%
    is.character()
  
  if(!char_col) cat(as_label( enquo(colour_var)), "is not character.")
  
  
  ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = {{ x_var }}, y = hp, colour = {{ colour_var }})) +
    labs(title = paste("Passed in x variable:", as_label( enquo(x_var))))
  
}

process_n_plot <- function(x_var, val, colour_var) {

  
  cat("You are filtering variable", as_label( enquo(x_var) ), "\n")
  
  mtcars %>% 
    filter({{ x_var }}  > val) %>% 
    my_plot(x_var = {{ x_var }}, colour_var = {{ colour_var }})
  
  
}

process_n_plot(disp, 200, cyl)
#> You are filtering variable disp 
#> cyl is not character.
```

[image]

```r
my_plot(mtcars, disp, cyl)
#> cyl is not character.
```

[image]

In the end, you can `enquo` so that `as_label` works and, surprisingly, `{{}}` will still know what to do. The same applies if you use `ensym` and `as_string`.

You could also simply do:

```
geom_point(aes(x = {{ x_var }}  , y = hp, colour = {{colour_var}})) +
labs(title = paste("Passed in x variable:", as_label( enquo(x_var) )))
```

Using `{{passing_arg}}` (same as using `!!enquo(passing_arg)`) solves the passing of arguments across functions.

As to why the original function was only working for `colour_var`, for reasons I still don't quite understand, `ensym()` was interpreting the `x_var` argument promise as a simple string. Once you had transformed the promise, e.g. by using it in another function call as I did with `colour_var`, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically correct, the `{{ }}` syntax is a shortcut to `!!enquo()`. Using `{{}}` assumes you never need the intermediary evaluated expression. Since you want to call `as_label`, then that shortcut is not appropriate for you because you need the unevaluated expression in that case.

Also note that `enquo` and `ensym` behave differently when passed a string. `ensym()` will turn that value into a symbol while `enquo()` will keep it as a character literal

```
f1 <- function(x) rlang::qq_show(!!enquo(x))
f2 <- function(x) rlang::qq_show(!!ensym(x))
f1("hello")
# ^"hello"
f2("hello")
# hello
```

which also effects how they are turned into labels

```
g1 <- function(x) as_label(enquo(x))
g2 <- function(x) as_label(ensym(x))
g1("hello")
# [1] "\"hello\""
g1(hello)
# [1] "hello"
g2("hello")
# [1] "hello"
g2(hello)
# [1] "hello"
```

When working in the tidyverse, it's important to keep track of which functions need symbols/expressions to be injected into the call, which functions need the unevaulated symbols/expressions themselves, and which can accept raw character values.

You also need to be mindful when passing values through to other functions. Normally the functions only look at the variable names passed directly to them. If you want to pass values "through" without evaluating them, you would need to use `!!` or `{{}}` as long as there is a rlang function there on the other side to make sense of it.

```
foo <- function(x) {
  ensym(x)
}
a1 <- function(x) {
  foo(x)
}
a2 <- function(x) {
  foo({{x}})
}
a3 <- function(x) {
  foo(!!ensym(x))
}
a1(test)
# x
a2(test)
# test
a3(test)
# test
```

See how only the latter two look all "all the way up" to find `test`

There are three ways to capture parmaters with `rlang`: quo (quosure), expr (expression) and sym (symbol). A `sym()` or symbol is just a single variable or column name. An `expr()` or expression can be a variable with function calls or operators involving other variables. Examples would be `x+y` or `foo(x)`. And a `quo()` or quosure is an expression that also keeps track of where it was defined in case it needs to look up values for any of the variables you pass in. Knowing which one is right for your particular use case can also make a big difference.

Comment: Thank you! This is great summary of the options available! Much more concise than what I have written...And the bottom line is: still some way to go for me to master the full suite of tools in the tidyverse!

Comment: also, it seems that `{{}}` is smart enough to treat an already `enquo()`'d variable the right way? how is that possible? just a fluke in my particular case?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what scenario you are refering to in that case, but `enquo` does look to see if you were trying to expand an expression that was passed to the function. These both return the same thing: `foo <- function(x) {enquo(x)}; foo(!!quo(x+1)); foo(x+1)`